# Can't modify global integer variable with user input from a GtkSpinButton widget

Tags: c++, c, integer, gtk, gtk3

I wrote a simple program using GTK and glade to allow the user to enter a number in a GtkSpinButton. Once the user hits the enter key (activate signal) the global variable should be changed to whatever the user entered in. Unfortunately that doesn't work and when I print out the global variable in the main function it simply spits out a zero. When I did this same thing with a string and a GtkEntry box it worked just fine. Here is the source code:

```
//gtkspinbox test program
// g++ -rdynamic -c lol.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0)
// g++ lol.o -o lol $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0)





#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkx.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <regex>
GtkWidget *lolwindow;
GtkWidget *lolfixed;
GtkWidget *lolentry;
GtkBuilder  *builder;
int lol;


extern "C" void on_lolentry_activate(GtkEntry *e, gpointer user_data){
lol = gtk_spin_button_get_value_as_int(GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(lolentry));

gtk_widget_destroy(lolwindow);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);//initializes gtk
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("lol.glade");//reads the xml file generated by glade
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL); 
    lolwindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lolwindow"));
    g_signal_connect(lolwindow, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    lolfixed = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lolfixed"));
    lolentry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lolentry"));


    gtk_widget_show(lolwindow);
    gtk_main();

    cout << lol << "\n";
}
```

and the glade file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment1">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">100</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="lolwindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">enter a number lmao</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed" id="lolfixed">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="lolentry">
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">80</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="adjustment">adjustment1</property>
            <signal name="activate" handler="on_lolentry_activate" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">161</property>
            <property name="y">95</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look at [mre] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the maximum value of the adjustment variable in glade was set to zero and that's why the global variable was being set to zero. Once I entered a different value for the maximum value the problem went away.